# GCC linker search path when cross-compiling

Tags: gcc, cross-compilation, ld

I have various tool chain directories on my linux machine for compiling under specific compiler versions.  I have a problem where the linker (in the tool chain dir) is selecting a library file from the native machine (/lib, for example) rather than the one in the tool chain (/toolchain/lib/...).  This results in various linker errors such as:

```
/opt/foo/cross_x86_64_v9b/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux/9.2.0/../../../../bin/x86_64-linux-ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxmlrpc_client.so.3: undefined reference to `curl_easy_getinfo@CURL_OPENSSL_4'
```

The link is failing because it is linking /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxmlrpc_client.so.3 (native file on my Ubuntu) instead of /opt/foo/cross_x86_64_v9b/lib64/libxmlrpc_client.so.3 (tool chain version).

Here's the search paths as far as I can figure:

```
/opt/foo/cross_x86_64_v9b/bin/x86_64-linux-ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR
SEARCH_DIR("/opt/foo/cross_x86_64_v9b/x86_64-linux/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("/opt/foo/cross_x86_64_v9b/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("/opt/foo/cross_x86_64_v9b/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("/opt/foo/cross_x86_64_v9b/x86_64-linux/lib");
```

If I remove the libxml... files from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu then the link succeeds, so somehow that path is being searched ahead of the SEARCH_DIR above.  All the system libraries being linked should be under /opt/foo/cross_x86_64_v9b.

Neither LD_PATH nor LD_LIBRARY_PATH are defined in my environment.  Why is the linker searching /lib before /opt/foo/cross_x86_64_v9b/lib64/?  How can I correct this?

Comment: Does your build use `pkg-config`?

Comment: @StephenKitt: No, we have a complex makefile setup.

Answer (score 0):

Two quick ideas for you to consider:

1. The lib path you specify during the configure for `binutils` is added to this list of `SEARCH_DIR` paths. I'm not sure exactly where it is placed in that order, but you can easily verify this after including the option while configuring and installing.

   ```
   --with-lib-path=/opt/foo/cross_x86_64_v9b/lib64
   ```
2. Your search paths can be manually edited in `libc.so` and `libm.so`. This might cause other errors though so be careful...

   ```
   cp -uv /opt/foo/cross_x86_64_v9b/lib/libc.so{,.orig}
   cp -uv /opt/foo/cross_x86_64_v9b/lib/libm.so{,.orig}
   sed -e 's@/path1@/path2@g' /opt/foo/cross_x86_64_v9b/lib/libc.so.orig > /opt/foo/cross_x86_64_v9b/lib/libc.so
   sed -e 's@/path1@/path2@g' /opt/foo/cross_x86_64_v9b/lib/libm.so.orig > /opt/foo/cross_x86_64_v9b/lib/libm.so
   diff /opt/foo/cross_x86_64_v9b/lib/libc.so{,.orig}
   diff /opt/foo/cross_x86_64_v9b/lib/libm.so{,.orig}
   ```